# Multiple do loops in SAS

Tags: sas, iteration, do-loops

I have a dataset of money earned as a % every week in 2017 to 2018. Some don't have data at the start of 2017 as they didn't start earning until later on. The weeks are numbered as 201701, 201702 - 201752 and 201801 - 201852.

What I'd like to do is have 104 new variables called WEEK0 - WEEK103, where WEEK0 will have the first non empty column value of the money earned columns. Here is an example of the data:

```
MON_EARN_201701      MON_EARN_201702      MON_EARN_201703    MON_EARN_201704
     30                     21                  50                 65   
     .                       .                  30                 100   
     .                      102                 95                 85
```

Then I want my data to have the following columns (example)

```
WEEK0      WEEK1      WEEK2      WEEK3
  30         21         50         65
  30        100          .          .
  102        95         85          .
```

These are just small examples of a very large dataset.

I was thinking I'd need to try and do some sort of do loops so what I've tried so far is:

```
DATA want;
SET have;
ARRAY mon_earn{104} mon_earn_201701 - mon_earn_201752 mon_earn_201801 -mon_earn_201852;
ARRAY WEEK {104} WEEK0 - WEEK103;
DO i = 1 to 104;
IF mon_earn{i} NE . THEN;
WEEK{i} = mon_earn{i};
END;
END;
RUN;
```

This doesn't work as it doesn't fill the WEEK0 when the first value is empty.

If anymore information is needed please comment and I will add it in.

Comment: Switch your data to a long format and this will be infinitely easier.

Comment: How would I do it if it was in long format?

Comment: You would sort, you could start renumbering from the first not missing value.

Comment: Are you able to show me through answering the question? I don't understand how I'd renumber the whole dataset as each row's first non missing value is at a different week and I have 100,000 + rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you just need to find the starting point for copying.

First look thru the list of earnings by calendar month until you find the first  non missing value. Then copy the values starting from there into you new array of earnings by relative month.

```
data want;
  set have;
  array mon_earn mon_earn_201701 -- mon_earn_201852;
  array week (104);
  do i = 1 to dim(mon_earn) until(found);
    if mon_earn{i} ne . then found=1;
  end;
  do j=1 to dim(week) while (i+j<dim(mon_earn));
    week(j) = mon_earn(i+j-1);
  end;
run;
```

NOTE: I simplified the ARRAY definitions. For the input array I assumed that the variables are defined in order so that you could use positional array list.  For the WEEK array SAS and I both like to start counting from one, not zero.

Comment: Thank you that's worked. I'll be able to use this method going forward with other issues I'm having, so thanks again.

Comment: Sorry if this is a stupid question, but I'm struggling to understand fully how this works, are you able to message me somehow to explain?

Comment: What is confusing?  There are two ARRAY statements. Read how those work in the documentation. There are two DO loops. Again read how those work.  SAS DO loops are very powerful because you can combine iterative loops with WHILE or UNTIL boundary tests as done in this.  The index in the TARGET array starts with one and stops when you run out of entries from the SOURCE array.

Comment: I have read the documentation on Array statements before I raised the question, not everyone's brains work in the same way so somethings are harder for me to understand. I just wanted to understand fully how the code was working, in particular "until (found)" and "mon_earn(i+j-1)". I've not used do loops more than twice before so I am new to this. Again like I said "Sorry if this is a stupid question" which you seem to think it is so I apologize.

Comment: FOUND is a number variable that is either missing or 1.  SAS will treat nonmissing and nonzero values as TRUE.  So the loop runs UNTIL the first nonmissing value is FOUND.  Array indexes are integers. I, J and negative one are integers. The sum of them is another integer and is used as the index into the array.  Since J goes from 1 to ... and I is the location of the first value then I+J-1 is the location of the current value to copy.

Comment: Note that you do not need to use the goofy brackets `[]` or `{}` that the new documentation uses for arrays in data step code. Normal parentheses work just fine. I find that the visual difference they make in the code is just not worth the effort it takes to find those keys on the keyboard.

Comment: Oh right, I just assumed they needed it as it was in the documentation. Thanks for that tip! It'll save some time.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this if it was a long format. There's a chance you don't need it while in a long format.

```
proc sort data=have;
by ID week;
run;

data want;
set have;
by id; *for each group/id counter;
retain counter;
if first.id then counter=0; 
if counter=0 and not missing(value) then do;
counter=1; new_week=0; end;
if counter = 1 then new_week+1;
run;
```

If you really need it wide:

1. Find first not missing value and store index in i
2. Loop from i to end of week dimension
3. Assign week to mon_earned from i to end of week.

   ```
   data want;
       set have;
       array mon_earned(*) .... ;
       array week(*) ... ;
       found=0; i=0;

       do while(found=0);
          if not missing(mon_earned(i)) then found=1;
          i+1;
       end;

       z=0;
       do j=i to dim(week);
           week(z) = mon_earned(j); 
           z+1;
       end;
   run;
   ```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I do get the error "ERROR: Array subscript 0 out of range [1 - 104] for dimension 1 of array mon_earned at line 343 column
       16". I'm assuming I need to enter my variable names into the array i.e mon_earn_201701 - mon_earn_201752 mon_earn_201801 -mon_earn_201852 for the first array?

Answer (score 1):

You need a second index variable, call it `j`, to target the proper week assignment.  `j` is only incremented when a months earning is not missing.

This example code will 'squeeze out` all missing earnings; even those missing earnings that occurring after some earning has occurred. For example

earning: `. . . 10 . 120 . 25 …` will squeeze to
week: `10 120 25 …`

```
data have;
  array earn earn_201701-earn_201752 earn_201801-earn_201852;
  do _n_ = 1 to 1000;
     call missing (of earn(*));
     do _i_ = 1 + 25 * ranuni(123) to dim(earn);
       if ranuni(123) < 0.95 then
         earn(_i_) = round(10 + 125 * ranuni(123));
     end;
     output;
  end;
run;

data want;
  set have;
  array earn earn_201701-earn_201752 earn_201801-earn_201852;
  array week(0:103);

  j = -1;
  do i = 1 to dim(earn);
    if not missing(earn(i)) then do;
      j+1;
      week(j) = earn(i);
    end;
  end;

  drop i j;
run;
```

If you want to maintain interior missing earnings the logic would be

```
    if not missing(earn(i)) or j >=0 then do;
      j+1;
      week(j) = earn(i);
    end;
```